# Fuzzy search with Fuzzy.js and Tables? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to use Fuzzy for my fuzzy search thing I have going on but it is very slow and doesn't seem like my states are updating on time. [Here is a CodeSandbox with everything](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0j4j68w2j), and here is a snippet of my App.js:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
var fuzzy = require('fuzzy');
console.log(fuzzy)

var searching = false;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchWord: "",
      searchMatches: []
    }

    this.fuzzySearch = this.fuzzySearch.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  //fuzzy search
  fuzzySearch () {
    var list = keywords.keywords;
    var options = {
      pre: '<b>'
    , post: '</b>'
    , extract: function(el) { return el.action; }
    };
    var results = fuzzy.filter(this.state.searchWord, list, options);
    var matches = results.map(function(el) { return el.string; });
    this.setState({searchMatches: matches});
    console.log(this.state.searchMatches);
    // [ '<b>a<c>o<n>ing', 'a mighty <b>ear <c>a<n>oe' ]
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({searchWord: event.target.value});
    this.fuzzySearch()
  }


  render() {
    const labelId = uuidv4();
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
          <Search handleChange={this.handleChange} searchWord={this.state.searchWord}/>
          <WordTable searchMatches={this.state.searchMatches}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id="searchDiv">
        <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search Keyword and/or Action..." value={this.props.searchWord} name="searchWord" onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

class WordTable extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.results = this.results.bind(this);
  }

  results() {
    console.log("result");
    console.log(this.props.searchMatches.length)
    if(this.props.searchMatches.length > 0){
      var matches = this.props.searchMatches;
      return (
        matches.map(p => 
          <Row key={uuidv4()} action={p.action} keyword={p.keyword}/>
        )
      )
    } else {
      return(
          keywords.keywords.map(p => 
            <Row key={uuidv4()} action={p.action} keyword={p.keyword}/>
          )
      )
    }
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div id="table">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Keyword(s)</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {/*console.log(keywords.keywords[0])}
              {keywords.keywords.map((keyword, action) => 
                <Row keyword={keywords.keywords.keyword} action={keywords.keywords.action}/>

              )*/
              this.results()
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
          {JSON.stringify(this.props.actions, null, " ")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Row extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td key={uuidv4()} value={this.props.action}>{this.props.action}</td>
            <td key={uuidv4()} value={this.props.keyword}>{this.props.keyword}</td>
        </tr>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am not sure why my search is making my React app slow, it also doesn't seem like the `matches` or `searchMathes` variable/state are updating on time, but could it be just that `console.log` is doing something funky? I am new to React and JS so any explanation of what's going on or what you think might be going on would help a lot.

And on top of the search being very slow, my results don't show up in my `WordTable` table. Any ideas as to why?

And an explanation of my JSON, the actual file I am using has 6000+ objects in it that look like

```
{ "action": "this-is-the-action", "keyword": "this is the keyword"}
```

I just put some random ones in the CodeSandbox I made there, But the idea is that there are duplicate `action`s to different `keyword`s. I hope that explains that a little better. Thanks!

Comment: `searchMatches` seems to be one state behind (according to my `console.log` of it)

Comment: `this.setState` is asynchronous. If you need to access a recently updated state value, use `this.setState({ x: ... }, () => this.state.x...)`. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Here's Fuzzy https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy/blob/master/lib/fuzzy.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of things wrong with your initial solution.

1. as I said in my comment, `this.setState` is asynchronous/batched

following,

```
this.setState({ searchWord: event.target.value })
this.fuzzySearch()
```

might not (aka probably wont) work. Why? Because the time between `this.setState(...)` and accessing `this.state.searchWord` in `fuzzySearch` is small enough that React probably hasn't reconciled the new state yet.

2. your `WordTable` component was super wonky. You were passing a `string[]`, but it expected the original objects (with a shape like `{ action: string, keyword: string }`). You were also re-rendering *all* options if there were no matches... not sure if that was intended behaviour but it made it seem like everything matched when, in fact, nothing did.
3. not *really* a *problem* so much as an optimisation but there's really no point in computing and storing the filtered list - just compute it and pass it down as a prop after `searchWord` has changed. This also takes away the race condition in #1.

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3kr383ykxm) with all of the above implemented (a cleaned up a little).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! This was really insightful. I was looking through my code and realized some of the things you mentioned (after reading more on `setState`, and then I realized I was trying to put stings in my table instead of the object (which is why I was getting an error that `action` was `undefined`) Thanks for the explanation, it really helped!

Comment: A little unrelated but... is there an obvious way to sort of highlight the text/characters that are showing up in the search like in [this demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy/blob/master/examples/disney.html)? I can't seem to figure out how to go about it. I was thinking I would change `pre:` to `<b>` and `post:` to `</b>` (both in `options`) but I realized that the `string` is not rendering in the table, so it's not working as I had hoped.